# Delphi 2007 Unable to modify the data in beforescroll event using source code, Error: Dataset not in Edit or Insert Mode

Tags: delphi, listbox, delphi-2007, dbgrid

A bit of History:
I have a DBlistbox containing textt descriptions and I store just the codes of this in a mysql table which is displayed in a dbgrid. User can select multiple options and I like to process these and store as comma separated values in one of the columns (this column is invisible in the dbgrid).

Right now I can populate the listbox when the user scroll through the dbgrid using event Afterscroll and Formcreate. But when I try to process the list and update the myquery behind the dbrgid I get an error saying 'Dataset not in Edit or Insert mode' - I do this in beforescroll

Please help!!
I have tried to set the dataset to edit mode before changing then as soon the data is posted dbgrid seems to have funny characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, the DBListBox is not connected to the dataset lonked in the grid? This would explain why the grid's dataset is not set to edit mode when you change the data in the DBListBox.

Anyway, whenever you change data that has to go into the mysql table, you should switch this dataset into edit mode. Then you can place your coding of the comma separated values into the OnBeforePost event.

When the dataset scrolls without any change in the data of the listbox, there is no need to store any data. This is achieved with the above approach as without edit mode no BeforePost event will fire in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.   yes the listbox is not linked to the table. The listbox get updated as the user scroll to the next line where I highlight in the listbox the options the user chose. and what i wanted to do is that just before scroll, update the grid, to make things complicated i have set cachedupdate = true so if the user decided to cancel no updates will be posted to the database. May be i'm going about this all wrong. If you have better approach i'm all ears

Comment: You can do as I describe in my answer. When the user changes something in the listbox set the dataset into edit mode. Then when you scroll the dataset an automatic Post is issued, which should trigger the BeforePost event. There you can write to the fields as appropriate.

Comment: Excellent it worked, I used click even in the listbox to update since the cachedupdate is set to true in the dbgrid. Once again thank you for all the help.